# code repeat in overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, constructor

I've a class with some overloaded constructor and no default constructor. The overloaded constructor essentially do the same things but differ on the `type` of params provided. Let's say I've a class as follows -

```
struct info {
  int one;    // must be filled
  int two;    // can be empty
  int three;  // can be empty
}

class A {
    int a;
    double b;
    float c;
    info I;

  public:

    A(a,b,c,one) :
      a(a),
      b(b),
      c(c)
    {
        // some processing
        I.one = one;
        // some other processing
        ....
    }

    A(a,b,c,i) :
      a(a),
      b(b),
      c(c),
      I(i)
    {
        // some processing
        // some other processing
        ....
    }

}
```

The processing and some processing part is repeating and is slightly dependent on certain paths which are frequently edited, forcing us to do same and same changes to both places.

Can this be reduced to same constructor in some way? I was hoping to do something with constructor delegation, but wasn't able to think of a clever way to do this :/

Comment: please explain the downvotes.. I would gladly improve my question :)

Comment: I don't know, but it could be due to your failure to specify the types of the arguments in your constructors (i.e. `A(int a, int b, ...`), or just the fact that you have a lot of code....? The question seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can this be reduced to same constructor in some way?

Yes. In *C++11* there are *delegating constructor*.

For example:

```
class Foo {
public: 
  Foo(char x, int y) {}
  Foo(int y) : Foo('a', y) {} // Foo(int) delegates to Foo(char,int)
};
```

**EDIT:**

As requested, take your example:

```
class A {
 private:
  A (int _a, double _b, float _c) : a(_a),
                                    b(_b),
                                    c(_c) {
    // This constructor does a lots of stuff...
  }

 public:
  A (int _a, double _b, float _c, int _one) : A(_a, _b, _c) {
    I.one = _one
    // This constructor does nothing
    // Because A(_a, _b, _c) already does everything
  }

  A (int _a, double _b, float _c, info _info) : A(_a, _b, _c) {
    I = _info;
    // This constructor does nothing
    // Because A(_a, _b, _c) already does everything
  }
};
```

Comment: could you do this taking my example? Since I've a tricky condition where 1 overload is of the struct itself while another version is of its member.

Comment: @hg_git: you can create a private constructor that does common part and use it from your public constructors

Comment: Is this a valid syntax `I.one(one)` ?

Comment: I do not believe so.  It should only work for members, not members of members.

Comment: `A (int _a, double _b, float _c, info _info) : A(_a, _b, _c), I(_info)` is not valid either.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ups... too fast. Well I fixed it.

Comment: Thankyou for fixing my example, I couldn't share the original code and hence had to type this out. Stupid brain made some stupid types :/

Comment: Also it is acceptable to create private ctors? I mean I know it is perfectly valid syntax, but is it considered a bad practice or just fine?

Comment: @hg_git I think in this case should be fine. In general it should not be a problem, but obviously it depends on the specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Just create a proper ctor for `info`:

```
struct info {
  int one;    // must be filled
  int two;    // can be empty
  int three;  // can be empty

  info( int lone, int ltwo = 0, int lthree = 0 ) :
      one( lone ), two( ltwo ), three( lthree ) {}
};
```

then you only need one ctor for `class A` that accepts `info`, or you can express that explicitly:

```
 A(int la, double lb, double lc, int one) :
    A( la, lb, lc, info( one ) )
 {
 }
```

Comment: This is only viable if `info` can be a non-aggregate.  If it needs to be an aggregate you cannot supply a constructor.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm feeling stupid here but could you explain what you mean when saying - `If it needs to be an aggregate`.. what is meant by aggregate..

Comment: @hg_git see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special